# C++ Build: ld returned 1 exit status & undefined reference

Tags: c++, avr, atmega, atmel, atmelstudio

I'm developing a program for Atmega328p in Atmel Studio 6.1
This my library:

The cpp file:

```
#include "lcd_16x2.h"

// default constructor
lcd_16x2::lcd_16x2()
{

} //lcd_16x2

// default destructor
lcd_16x2::~lcd_16x2()
{
} //~lcd_16x2

void lcd_16x2::lcd_init()
{   
    // Setto i pin della porta LCD ad output
    LCD_DDR |= (1<< LCD_PIN_DATA) | (1 << LCD_PIN_CLK) | (1 << LCD_PIN_EN);

    // LCD e SIPO disabilitato
    LCD_EN_OFF();
    LCD_CLK_OFF();
    [...]
}

inline void lcd_16x2::shift_display_right()
{
    lcd_wc(0x05);
}

[...]
```

The header file:

```
#ifndef __LCD_16X2_H__
#define __LCD_16X2_H__


#define F_CPU 16000000UL

#include <avr/io.h>
#include "avr/cpufunc.h"

#define LCD_DDR DDRB
#define LCD_PORT PORTB
[...]

#define LCD_CLK_OFF() (LCD_PORT &= ~(1 << LCD_PIN_CLK))  // Set clock SIPO to LOW

[...]



#include <util/delay.h>

class lcd_16x2
{

//functions
public:
    lcd_16x2();
    ~lcd_16x2();
    void lcd_init();
    inline void lcd_set_cursor(char line, char address);
    inline void lcd_write_string(char *s);
    inline void clear_display();
    inline void return_home();
    inline void shift_display_right();
protected:
private:
    inline void lcd_write_bits_sipo(char d);

    inline void lcd_wc(char data, char del = 42);
    inline void lcd_wd(char data);
    inline void lcd_enable_tik();


}; //lcd_16x2

#endif //__LCD_16X2_H__
```

When i had only lcd_init() as public method in the class definition, all was ok and used to work fine. Then I added other methods to my class (clear_display(), shift_display_right() etc...) and I got these errors:

```
Error   3   ld returned 1 exit status   collect2.exe    0   0   LCD_driver
Error   2   undefined reference to `lcd_16x2::shift_display_right()'    C:\Users\...\LCD_driver\LCD_driver\Debug/.././LCD_driver.cpp    20  1   LCD_driver
```

The Output:

```
------ Build started: Project: LCD_driver, Configuration: Debug AVR ------
Build started.
Project "LCD_driver.cppproj" (default targets):
Target "PreBuildEvent" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(PreBuildEvent)'!='') was evaluated as (''!='').
Target "CoreBuild" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Atmel Studio 6.1\Vs\Compiler.targets" from project "C:\Users\Alessio\Documents\Projects\LCD_driver\LCD_driver\LCD_driver.cppproj" (target "Build" depends on it):
    Task "RunCompilerTask"
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Atmel Studio 6.1\shellUtils\make.exe all 
        Building file: .././LCD_driver.cpp
        Invoking: AVR8/GNU C Compiler : 3.4.4
        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Atmel Toolchain\AVR8 GCC\Native\3.4.1056\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin\avr-g++.exe" -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -DDEBUG  -O1 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -g2 -Wall -mmcu=atmega328p -c -MD -MP -MF "LCD_driver.d" -MT"LCD_driver.d" -MT"LCD_driver.o"   -o "LCD_driver.o" ".././LCD_driver.cpp"
        In file included from .././LCD_driver.cpp:10:0:
C:\Users\Alessio\Documents\Projects\LCD_driver\LCD_driver\lcd_16x2.h(51,14): inline function 'void lcd_16x2::shift_display_right()' used but never defined [enabled by default]
          inline void shift_display_right();
                      ^
        Finished building: .././LCD_driver.cpp
        Building target: LCD_driver.elf
        Invoking: AVR8/GNU Linker : 3.4.4
        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Atmel Toolchain\AVR8 GCC\Native\3.4.1056\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin\avr-g++.exe" -o LCD_driver.elf  lcd_16x2.o LCD_driver.o   -Wl,-Map="LCD_driver.map" -Wl,--start-group -Wl,-lm  -Wl,--end-group -Wl,--gc-sections -mmcu=atmega328p 
        LCD_driver.o: In function `main':
C:\Users\Alessio\Documents\Projects\LCD_driver\LCD_driver\Debug/.././LCD_driver.cpp(20,1): undefined reference to `lcd_16x2::shift_display_right()'
collect2.exe(0,0): ld returned 1 exit status
        make: *** [LCD_driver.elf] Error 1
        The command exited with code 2.
    Done executing task "RunCompilerTask" -- FAILED.
Done building target "CoreBuild" in project "LCD_driver.cppproj" -- FAILED.
Done building project "LCD_driver.cppproj" -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded or up-to-date, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I can't understand the problem (before adding some methods all worked fine!)...

Thank's in advance

NOTE: The libm is loaded into the linker...

Comment: Could you show your LCD_driver.cpp? better yet, a complete MVE.

Comment: @tipaye Looks like the OP already shows the relevant part with the definition.

Comment: Try to remove all the "inline" from your hpp and cpp files. Then, it should work.

Comment: @Varius Yes the problem is in the inline declaration. But I need to define the functions as inline... I can't understand how to call the inline function from the main program....

Comment: Ok, if it has to be inline then remove the whole definition from the cpp file and declare AND define it as inline in the hpp File. This is actually how inline methods are normally treated.